# Move @ngrx-store to new version

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have @ngrx-store in my app, and now Im going to update actions, reducers and effect to last version... until now, with old action/reducer/effect everything is worked ok, but now I can not get data from effects, getting this error

> ERROR TypeError: 
>           Dispatch expected an object, instead it received a function.
>           If you're using the createAction function, make sure to invoke the function
>           before dispatching the action. For example, someAction should be someAction().

Here is my action

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IAppAll} from "./../../app.model";

export const loadApps = createAction("[App] Load Apps");

export const loadAppsSuccess = createAction(
  "[App] Load AppSuccess",
  props<{ sites: IAppAll[] }>()
);
```

here is reducer

```
import { Action, createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import * as AppActions from "../actions/app.actions";
import { initialState, State } from "../state/site.model";

export const appeFeatureKey = "app";

const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(AppActions.loadApp, state => ({ ...state })),
  on(AppActions.createApp, (state, { app}) => ({ ...state }))
);

export function reducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return appReducer(state, action);
}
```

And here is effect

```
export class AppEffects {
  loadApps$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(appActions.loadApps),
      concatMap(() =>
        this.appService
          .getApps()
          .pipe(
            map((apps: IAppAll[]) => appActions.loadAppsSuccess({ apps }))
          )
      )
    )
  );
```

My json is like this

```
[{key: value, key1: value1},
{key: value, key1: value1}]
```

This data worked correctly on "last" `ngrx/store` version
In `action <props>` is object, but how to change this?

thnx